# Dropbox 1.6 configuration

Tags: 12.04, dropbox

I'm working with ubuntu 12.04 and I installed dropbox 1.6.0.
After installation, it working.
The dropbox icon is in the notification area and I can configure it.
The most important for me is to configure a proxy with username and password authentication.
But ... after a while (I don't know exactly because it is a server and I don't connect to it every day) the icon dispears.  Even the synch continue working.
And now I have to change the proxy password.
So how can I do if I don't have the dropbox icon ?

Comment: You mean dropbox is starting automatically when system starts ?  Yes.

Comment: `man dropbox` ;-)

Comment: ok, I 'manned' dropbox but nothing about configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Dropbox command line instructions script, then all you need to do to add a folder to the Selective Sync "do not sync" list is enter the following command in your Terminal.

You can download "command line instructions script" here: -              https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py

and set as

```
$ /path/to/dropbox.py exclude add ~/Dropbox/path/to/folder/
```

Simply substitute the /path/to/ to the actual paths to the CLI script and the folder or file, respectively.

Use these command to configure the dropbox :-

```
$ sudo http_proxy=http://your_proxy:proxy_port dropbox start -i

$ dropbox -a   ( to show all dropbox commands)

$ dropbox lansync  y/n  (enables or disables LAN sync)

$ dropbox autostart y/n (start automatically at login)
```

You can find more information here:- https://www.dropbox.com/help/175/en